# Adding the PPA does not update Geary

Tags: ppa, geary

I have installed Geary mail client 0.4.0 from software center. After I read there is a new version, 0.4.1, I added the PPA through terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Still, I am stuck with 0.4.0.

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

this -

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Only updates the repository , use

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of also intelligently handles anging dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary.  So, dist-Upgrade command may remove some packages.

As mentioned before update will install all the newest packages , If you only want to update a particular package use-

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

But if everything other then that package is already updated , you can directly use **UPDATE.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to run :

> sudo apt-get upgrade

After `apt-get update`

P.S this will update all the packages on your system
To update a particular package use :

> sudo apt-get install package-name

in your case :

> sudo apt-get install geary

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands on terminal to update geary,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install geary
```

Comment: upgrade will update all the installed applications.To update geary see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/98412/8698) is not the same, but the same answers generally apply. Mostly the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/117086/8698) by [Luis Alvarado](https://askubuntu.com/users/7035/luis-alvarado).

And to add on all the current answers here, I would like to add 1 more reason that I keep having with the Firefox beta PPA. (Though the other answers here are most likely the correct solution for you)

When trying to upgrade a package by adding a new PPA, if the package doesn't get upgraded you can check on launchpad to make sure there is a successful build that is available for your version of the OS.

For example I have added the PPA for Firefox beta.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

My system is Ubuntu 13.10 x64. So checking the [PPA on launchpad (https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next/+packages)](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/firefox-next/+packages), it seems that, currently, the build for that specific Ubuntu version on the 64 bit architecture failed. Thus the package did not get upgraded and I got stuck with the release version of Firefox instead of the beta version.

[image: Failed build for Raring amd64]

As long as the PPA is on launchpad, you can always do this check.
In your case, you need to check https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa/+packages.
Currently there doesn't seem to be any failed build, but this answer can be helpful for future & similar problems.